# Performance issues when creating UIView Sublclass from xib (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, xcode, performance, uiview, subclass

#### The idea

---

In my application, I want to create a **custom button** by subclassing a UIView, including an icon **image** and a **label**. When the user tap the button, the icon and the label color change and I use the information that the button is pressed in an other class. (Not really important).

#### The problem

---

- I need to display 10 to 20 buttons of that kind in my
  UIViewController. The first button is working fine, but **button
  after button, they become less reactive**. The last one need up to 1
  seconde to change it’s color.
- Also, Xcode doesn't really like that; my Storyboard where I
  implemented my custom UIView become **extremely slow** and the agent
  rendering the views often crash.
- Moreover, my app takes **forever to load.**

#### The way I've done that

---

I have created a class "`@IBDesignable class IconButton: UIView{}`" and I load the view form a xib file.

There is two outlets :

1. `@IBOutlet var iconImageOutlet: UIImageView!`
2. `@IBOutlet var titleLabelOutlet: UILabel!`

I want my button’s title and image to be IBInspectable. So I do this :

```
@IBInspectable var buttonText:String = "text_01"{
    didSet{
        titleLabelOutlet.text = buttonText
    }
}

@IBInspectable var buttonImage:UIImage? = UIImage(named: "image_01"){
    didSet{
        iconImageOutlet.image = buttonImagesetColor()
    }
}
```

I have implemented these methods to instantiate the view :

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    xibSetup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    xibSetup()
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder(){
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    xibSetup()
}

func xibSetup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = boundsview.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(view)
    setColor()
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "IconButton", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
}

private func setColor(){
    iconImageOutlet.image = iconImageOutlet.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
        if self.isActive {
            self.iconImageOutlet.tintColor = UIColor.pindexBlue()
            self.titleLabelOutlet.textColor = UIColor.pindexBlue()

            let changeColor = CATransition()
            changeColor.type = kCATransitionFade
            changeColor.duration = 0.1

            CATransaction.begin()

            CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
                    self.titleLabelOutlet.textColor = UIColor.blue
                    self.titleLabelOutlet.layer.add(changeColor, forKey: nil)
            }
            self.titleLabelOutlet.textColor = UIColor.blue
            self.titleLabelOutlet.layer.add(changeColor, forKey: nil)

            CATransaction.commit()

        } else {
            self.iconImageOutlet.tintColor = UIColor.blue
            self.titleLabelOutlet.textColor = UIColor.gray

            let changeColor = CATransition()
            changeColor.type = kCATransitionFade
            changeColor.duration = 0.1

            CATransaction.begin()

            CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
                self.titleLabelOutlet.textColor = UIColor.gray
                self.titleLabelOutlet.layer.add(changeColor, forKey: nil)
                }
            self.titleLabelOutlet.textColor = UIColor.gray
            self.titleLabelOutlet.layer.add(changeColor, forKey: nil)

            CATransaction.commit()
        }
    }  
}

private var isActive:Bool = false
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    isActive = !isActive
    setColor()
}
```

#### Conclusion

---

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, and nobody seams to have to same problem.

So if anyone have suppositions, thank you :)

*PS: Sorry for my bad English*